# compare dates to curdate wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date

Im trying to use a filter in wordpress for select all post of today:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date = CURDATE() ";
    return $where;
}
```

and not working but if using <= or >= get the posts.

thanks for your help

Comment: What type column is `post_date`?

Comment: the full query is SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'agenda_cultural' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future') AND DATE(wp_posts.post_date) = CURDATE()  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: damm, i guess my server is not working with the correct date. it has janueary 3 (here in Chile is still january 2). Using AND DATE(wp_posts.post_date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) it works

Comment: Adding "-1 DAY" is a bad idea. Couple of reasons - first, use DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY). Second, don't do it all - I'm sure you'll find it's not exactly one day different, rather a number of hours. I'll post a new answer with better syntax for you below.

Answer (score 1):

post_date is a DATETIME field I think, not a DATE field. Try something like `AND DATE(post_date) = CURDATE()` to compare just on date, not time.

Edit: You've now realised your MySQL server has the timezone set wrong. You can correct this on a per-connection basis. I'd suggest finding the bit of code where Wordpress connects to the database and adding these two lines of code after the connection. You may want to search for `mysql_connect` or `mysql_select_db` to find this.

```
$query = "SET time_zone = 'Chile/Santiago'";
mysql_query($query);
```

After you've done this then the following code should probably work, as per my original answer:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND DATE(post_date) = CURDATE() ";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: is not working neither. but DATETIME() is Y-m-d H:i:s. In any case it will be DATE(post_date) = DATE(CURDATE()) ?

Comment: DATE(CURDATE()) is the same as DATE() - it already returns a value of type "date". Comparing DATE(post_date) to CURDATE() should work.

Answer (score 0):

If `post_date` is a datetime or timestamp column, you should use:

```
AND post_date >= CURDATE()
AND post_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY        --- this is needed just in case
                                                --- your table has posts with 
                                                --- future dates (by error)
```

Comment: This is missing some brackets from the second CURDATE - should be CURDATE(). Regardless, Using "DATE(post_date) = CURDATE()" should be cleaner and produce the same results I believe?

Comment: @SpoonNZ: Thnx, added the missing brackets. It may be cleaner but then the query can't use any index on the table and it has to scan the whole table - and convert (every row's) datetime to date to make the comparison. If you have a few thousands posts or more, try to time the two versions.

Comment: @returnvoid: Dealing with dates and timezones is not an easy task. First, you have to find out how WordPress is storing the `post_date` datetimes. Does it use UTC (I think yes, but not sure) or other timezone? Then you have to decide what you mean by "today". "Today in Chile" is not the same as "today in Greece"

Comment: @returnvoid: You can also try the [WordPress brother site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30946/default-timezone-hardcoded-as-utc)